# C++ Wait x secound inside a loop

Tags: c++

I am trying to figure out how to wait inside a loop.
What I want to do is to click a button on a program and if a error happened it is going to show a error message for 3 seconds than disappear. All this is inside a loop that runs all the time.
I have tried ctime, sleep etc. But all of them freeze the program to the time has ended. And that isn't what I am looking for.

I have thought about getting the PC clock and + 3 seconds than make a if() to check if the clock == clock + 3. But i didn't find a way to get the clock time and do what i was thinking. And i know that their is a good way of doing what i want for this, but i just haven't figured out how. I just end up freezing the threads to the clock is done.

So it had been nice if someone can lead me in the right direction or/and maybe show me some examples on how to do this.

Comment: Show us the code you have so far.

Comment: You need an event loop if you want to avoid jamming your thread.

Comment: Thare isent mutch code to show. I have just tryd basic timer stuff. @stybl

Comment: show the dialog remember the current time, on each following iteration check how much time has passed if it is >3 seconds close the dialog

Comment: How do i make a event loop :) @tadman
It sounds like that is my solution :D

Comment: @MayBoyLovesYou You can start by Googling it and try something. Then, if it does not work, come back with something more substantial (like code).

Comment: "PC clock and + 3 " Nice and simple and can work... right up until the PC's clock gets syncronized with another timesource. [Take a look at std::chrono::steady_clock](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/steady_clock) for a better way.

Comment: *"`clock == old_clock + 3`"*, even worst than comparing float for equality :-) You probably want `clock >= old_clock + 3`.

Comment: What UI library are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pausing main thread for some amount of time will freeze the whole program regardless of the way you are using to pause.
I am not really familiar with event-loop mentioned in the comments above. However I would achieve the task using std::thread (c++11), if you're not familiar with c++11, there are many other non-standarised ways of of creating threads, namely [pthread](http://www.bogotobogo.com/cplusplus/multithreading_pthread.php) in linux and in windows you can use [windows.h](http://www.bogotobogo.com/cplusplus/multithreading_win32A.php) as in the link.
So let's talk some C++:
For example you can write a function to show the error message, wait a number of seconds and return;
The function would have the following signature

```
void myFunction(char errMsg[], unsigned int durationSeconds);
```

then you can call it from the main thread (the function you were showing the message in), using:

```
std::thread(myFunction("error message", 3));
```

Now back to your question, C++11 also offers a convenient way for pausing a thread for some amount of time without a while loop, you can use the code below for it:

```
std::chrono::seconds interval(durationSeconds);
std::this_thread::sleep_for(interval);
```

just write them after showing the message and that should help.

Comment: Unrelated: [Event loop](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Event_loop). Basically it is a loop that blocks waiting for messages. A mouse click on the UI would be a message. Timer expiry is a message. Job completion would be a message. Network packet arrival, probably a message. When a message arrives, the loop wakes up, does whatever it needs to do to handle the message, and goes back to sleep. These are useful in programs where you want the appearance of nondeterministic behaviours and don't want a to deal with thread synchronization. You often see them in embedded systems and GUIs.